# Can two Creepers be attached to the same Keeper?

Tags: fluxx

Some Creepers say they must be attached to a Keeper if you have a Keeper in play. If you end up with two such Creepers, and only one Keeper, can both Creepers be attached to the lone Keeper? Or is there a limit of one Creeper per Keeper?

I haven't found anything in the official Rules or FAQ, which came with the game, to address this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a discussion on BGG http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/917715/multiple-creeper-question

> Q:Can a single keeper have more then one creeper attached? Evil/Malfunction, two Brain Parasites, etc.
>
> A:Yes, as long as both Creepers are allowed to attach to the card, there can be two Creepers attached to the same card.
>
> Q:Also, do you choose which keepers get the attached creeper if you can?
>
> A:Yes, if there is more than one Keeper that a Creeper can attach to when it's played, you get to choose. If it can't attach to anything when it's played, it stays unattached and attaches to the first Keeper it can.